# How to get products that the sellers have reduced their prices in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, laravel-8

I have a table called products that each time a user updates their product, a new row is saved in another table called product_price_history.

My Tables :

**products :**

```
id  (primary key)
name  (varchar)
price  (decimal)
```

**product_price_history :**

```
id  (primary key)
product_id  (fk to products)
price  (decimal)
created_at (dateTime)
```

**My Models :**

- Product
- ProductPriceHistory

I have written the relationship of the child table inside the product model as follows

```
class Product extends Model {


  public function history()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(ProductPriceHistory::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }


}
```

How do I write a query in Laravel that displays a list of products with declining prices?
In other words, show the list of products whose prices have recently decreased.

```
   $result = Product::whereHas('history' , function($query){

   // I do not know what to write here ...


   })->get();
```

Comment: what is 'recently' to you?

Answer (score 1):

The query you created is correct, just add the descending order filter

the query will be like this:

```
   $result = Product::whereHas('history' , function($query){
       $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
   })->get();
```

Comment: how would an "order by" help in a query that is checking the existence of any records?

Comment: I want to show only the products that the sellers have reduced their prices. @samuel-lujan

Comment: There is two ways to go. The first one you can get or the first or the last insert of the history prices and see if this values is GT or LT then the value.

Or you can add some fields in the products table, like is_promotional and promotional_value. then you should search by this value :)